# Why does the subtotal not add with each other?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { addToCart, removeFromCart } from "../actions/cartActions";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
function CartScreen(props) {
  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart);

  const { cartItems } = cart;

  const productId = props.match.params.id;
  const qty = props.location.search
    ? Number(props.location.search.split("=")[1])
    : 1;
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const removeFromCartHandler = (productId) => {
    dispatch(removeFromCart(productId));
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (productId) {
      dispatch(addToCart(productId, qty));
    }
  }, []);

  const checkoutHandler = () => {
    props.history.push("/signin?redirect=shipping");
  };

  return (
    <div className="cart">
      <div className="cart-list">
        <ul className="cart-list-container">
          <li>
            <h3>Shopping Cart</h3>
            <div>Price</div>
          </li>
          {cartItems.length === 0 ? (
            <div>Cart is empty</div>
          ) : (
            cartItems.map((item) => (
              <li>
                <div className="cart-image">
                  <img src={item.image} alt="product" />
                </div>
                <div className="cart-name">
                  <div>
                    <Link to={"/product/" + item.product}>{item.name}</Link>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    Qty:
                    <select
                      value={item.qty}
                      onChange={(e) =>
                        dispatch(addToCart(item.product, e.target.value))
                      }
                    >
                      {[...Array(item.countInStock).keys()].map((x) => (
                        <option key={x + 1} value={x + 1}>
                          {x + 1}
                        </option>
                      ))}
                    </select>
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      className="button"
                      onClick={() => removeFromCartHandler(item.product)}
                    >
                      Delete
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="cart-price">${item.price}</div>
              </li>
            ))
          )}
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div className="cart-action">
        <h3>
          Subtotal ( {cartItems.reduce((a, c) => a + c.qty, 0)} items) : ${" "}
          {cartItems.reduce((a, c) => a + c.price * c.qty, 0)}
        </h3>
        <button
          onClick={checkoutHandler}
          className="button primary full-width"
          disabled={cartItems.length === 0}
        >
          Proceed to Checkout
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CartScreen;
```

The main purpose of this code is to display a webpage by the name of cart screen.
Inside the cart screen are all the items I want to buy from a different page taken from another js file which has all the date for those products.

I want to highlight this particular code right here.

```
<h3>
Subtotal ( {cartItems.reduce((a, c) => a + c.qty, 0)} items) : ${" "}
{cartItems.reduce((a, c) => a + c.price * c.qty, 0)}
</h3>
```

The way this code works is:
The subtotal counts how many items in total I have inside the cart and then takes each product cost and multiplies it by their quantity before adding everything and telling me how much everything I want to buy costs before I want to buy it. The total price section works completely fine.

What is baffling me is how the subtotal of how many items are in the cart doesn't seem to work how I am intending it to.

It works fine if I just have 2 separate items in the cart which I want to buy 1 of in which the subtotal tells me that I have a total of 2 items in the cart which is right. But as soon as I want to buy 2 of from one item the subtotal somehow turns from the previous 2 item statement into 12 or rather 1 for the one item and 2 for the other item I want to buy 2 of. For some reason they don't combine when they should be showing 3 and not 12.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your `qty` and `price` properties are not strings but numbers. If you store these values as numbers, your `.reduce()` methods will work as expected:

```js
const cartItems = [
  { qty: 1, price: 5.99 },
  { qty: 2, price: 25.0 },
  { qty: 5, price: 10.0 },
];

cartItems.reduce((a, c) => a + c.qty, 0); 
// => 8

cartItems.reduce((a, c) => a + c.price * c.qty, 0);
// => 105.99
```

If you use the `+` operator with numbers, it sums them as you'd expect. However, if you store your numbers as strings and you try to calculate their sum, it will actually concatenate them into a new string.

If you use the `*` operator, you implicitly convert the strings to numbers and that's why the total price works, but the total number of items not:

```js
const cartItems = [
  { qty: '1', price: '5.99' },
  { qty: '2', price: '25.00' },
  { qty: '5', price: '10.00' },
];

cartItems.reduce((a, c) => a + c.qty, 0);
// => "0125"

cartItems2.reduce((a, c) => a + c.price * c.qty, 0);
// => 105.99
```

To fix this, you either need to make sure that you store `qty` and `price` as numbers or convert them in your `.reduce()`.

```js
const cartItems = [
  { qty: '1', price: '5.99' },
  { qty: '2', price: '25.00' },
  { qty: '5', price: '10.00' },
];

cartItems.reduce((a, c) => a + Number(c.qty), 0);
// => 8
```